# Is there a way to refer to the class' @brief in the doxygen?

Tags: c++, doxygen

Let's say, we have the following doxygen comment:

```
/**
 * @brief The cool class.
 *
 * More info...
 */
class A {};
```

I'd like that "The cool class." brief has been appeared on some arbitrary place. For example, I'd like to make a table with list of some arbitrary classes and theirs brief descriptions. So, I have option to write briefs manually here, but it looks like this briefs will be the same as those ones. Therefore, it'll be nice to place some construction into this table in order to skip information doubling.

Comment: Which version of doxygen do you use? Despite the given answer: what did you try so far?

Comment: doxygen's version is 1.9.1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the `\copybrief` command is suited for this, just a mock-up with a list:

```
/// \file
///
/// Lets try to make a list:
/// - \copybrief A
/// - \copybrief B

/// \brief The cool class
class A {};

/// \brief The other cool class
class B {};
```

Which results here in the list in the detailed description of the file:

[image]

Comment: WOW! It's cool! It looks like someone was already facing with this issue before me.

Comment: Yes I found the first occurrence in the release 1.5.6. (May 18, 2008)